# Hardwood Flush Door or Pinewood (softwood) flush door, which is better?

Tags: doors

We are renovating our home and replacing all old-broken doors.. We are too confused between getting hardwood or pinewood(softwood) for flush door.

Apart from Hardness\Softness and difference in their weight (hardwood is heavier), what else key differences are there for choosing them for Flush doors.

Cost wise, here in India, Pinewood is costlier than Hardwood due to its light weight property.

Are there more points to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warp is a very important point to consider. Though depending on the species and the cut, this answer could very a lot.

Pine may be lighter, but also has a much higher moisture content.  If the door is kiln dried and sealed quickly, you can keep it from absorbing the moisture from the humid air.  Also if it is air-dried, it may be more stable. I have seen pine warp significantly due to changes in humidity, and being in India -- especially if you are in the South or East -- I would wonder if this wouldn't be the case as well.  (especially if it was a knotty pine)

Hardwoods are denser, and generally have a lower moisture content allowing them to dry well and remain more stable lowering the chance for major warp.

My opinion: Go hardwood.

Comment: I agree with John.  The reason for going with a lighter door would be that you are worried about the door hitting something or you don't feel the hinges are secured enough to handle the weight over long-term.

Answer (score 0):

Using pine for any door will work.so pine is good for flush doors because its a softwood and you won't see much difference. Pine will move according to weather but it's ok with the pine.